# C Programming linked list pointer returning weird value

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I was having some problem when trying to merge two sorted linked list into one. Here is my code:

```
void sortedMerge(LinkedList *l1, LinkedList *l2, LinkedList *result)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (l1->size > 0 && l2->size > 0) {
        if (l1->head < l2->head) {
            removeNode(l1, 0);
            insertNode(result, i++, l1->head);
        }
        else {
            removeNode(l2, 0);
            insertNode(result, i++, l2->head);
        }
    }
}

int insertNode(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value)
{
    ListNode *pre, *cur;
    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index > ll->size + 1)
        return -1;
    if (ll->head == NULL || index == 0) {
        cur = ll->head;
        ll->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        ll->head->item = value;
        ll->head->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }
    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        pre->next->item = value;
        pre->next->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    } 
    return -1;
}

int removeNode(LinkedList *ll, int index)
{
    ListNode *pre, *cur;
    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index >= ll->size)
        return -1;
    if (index == 0) {
        cur = ll->head->next;
        free(ll->head);
        ll->head = cur;
        ll->size--;
        return 0;
    }
    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL) {    
        if (pre->next == NULL)
            return -1;
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        ll->size--;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Code snippet from my main function:

```
case 1:
        printf("Input an integer that you want to add to the linked list 1:\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        j = insertSortedLinkedList(&ll1, i);
        printf("Linked list 1 : ");
        printList(&ll1);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Input an integer that you want to add to the linked list 2:\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        j = insertSortedLinkedList(&ll2, i);
        printf("Linked list 2 : ");
        printList(&ll2);
        break;
    case 3:
        sortedMerge(&ll1, &ll2, &resultMergedList); 
        printf("The resulting linked list is:\n");
        printList(&resultMergedList);
        break;
```

So I entered `2,4,6` for **l1** and `1,2,3` for **l2**. The expected output should be `1,2,2,3,4,6`. However, I am getting `4229048, 4228432, 4228565, 0`.
I was thinking is it because the output that I am getting were memory location?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: main function was basically taking the inputs for l1 and l2 then call the sortedMerge. Inside the sortedMerge, I then call removeNode and insertNode

Comment: only way to replicate and debug issue is with working program ( may be other undefined behaviour going on in main )

Comment: The insertSortedLinkedList() was working fine because it's from my other questions. I didn't post it because it was too long. Basically that function is to populate l1 and l2.

Comment: downvoted as incomplete program unable to be debugged - see **[mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** particularly the complete part

Comment: I already posted the code snippet from my main function. The entire main function was too long as I think it's not good to post the whole chunk of code for concise purpose. Then as for the insertSortedLinkedList from case 1 and 2, I am pretty sure it was working fine. So basically the whole chunk of code can start from case 3.

Comment: you posted a small snippet which hints at another function ( which is also not posted ). part of creating  an mvce is reducing the problem down to a minimal program with the same issue. if you are unable to do that, at least a full program replicates the issue

Answer (score 3):

As kcraigie has pointed out, you should create a new node with it `item`. The compiler should warn you that you are passing a pointer where you need an integer.

The quick fix seems to be this:

```
    removeNode(l1, 0);
    insertNode(result, index++, l1->head->item);
```

but it isn't: `removeNode` will change `l1`'s head, which might well be `NULL`. Dereferencing `NULL` will likely give you a segmentation violation.

Something else is wrong with that fix: If it succeds, it adds the item of the node after the remopved head. So do something like this:

```
    int item = l1->head->item;

    removeNode(l1, 0);
    insertNode(result, index++, item);
```

With that corrected, your merge still isn't complete: You will eventually encounter the case where one of the lists is empty. You don't treat that case.

And there's room for improvement. You take the easy route and just destroy the lists and create a new list with the same data. That's a valid solution to your problem, but the problem can be solved by just rearranging (or relinking) the existing nodes.

Here's a corrected version of your approach for merging the lists:

```
void sortedMerge(LinkedList *l1, LinkedList *l2, LinkedList *result)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (l1->size > 0 && l2->size > 0) {
        if (l1->head->item < l2->head->item) {
            int item = l1->head->item;

            removeNode(l1, 0);
            insertNode(result, index++, item);
        } else {
            int item = l2->head->item;

            removeNode(l2, 0);
            insertNode(result, index++, item);
        }
    }

    while (l1->size) {
        int item = l1->head->item;

        removeNode(l1, 0);
        insertNode(result, index++, item);
    }

    while (l2->size) {
        int item = l2->head->item;

        removeNode(l2, 0);
        insertNode(result, index++, item);
    }    
}
```

You could refactor the repeated removal-and-insertion into a new function.

Comment: But with the solution you provided, when I entered 1,2,3 for l1 and 2,4,6 for l2. The output I get was 1,2,1,1 which was really strange. Also, the last 2 numbers from l1 and l2 were missing too. Any ideas?

Comment: Because your code isn't complete, my answer can't be a complete solution. I explain why your last nodes are missing: The `while` loop stops when one of the lists is empty, but you have to take care of the nodes that are still in the other list.

Comment: There's another bug: `if (l1->head < l2->head)` compares pointers, you want to compare the item values: `if (l1->head->item < l2->head->item)`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it also. But do you think am I on the correct logic track to solve this problem? Or I have to come out with another algorithm?

Comment: You are on the right track. As I said, popping nodes off the original lists and appending them to the new one is a good solution. But you have to make some changes and also add code to treat the remaining nodes. I've added a woring example.

Comment: Overall, the implementation of insertion and removal via index seems a bit clumsy and complicated to me. If you added a field `ListNode *tail` to you list, you could make adding to and removing from both front an end, very common cases, very efficient.

Comment: Is there any down side to add or remove via index?

Comment: Well, your list just stores the head. That means that you must traverse the whole list whan appending to the tail. That's not a problem for short lists, but if you have "real" lists, that's a performance issue. Your merging code needs two actions: pop off the head (fast) and append to the end (slow in your implementaion). If you had a tail member in your list, you could append to the end very quickly too. Of course, that introduces an invariant: You must take care that the tail is really always the last node or null.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling in insertNode() on the resulting linked list with l1->head instead of l1->head->item.

Instead, try inserting the head's item to result before freeing it:

```
while (l1->size > 0 && l2->size > 0) {
    if (l1->head < l2->head) {
        insertNode(result, index++, l1->head->item);
        removeNode(l1, 0);
    } else {
        insertNode(result, index++, l2->head->item);
        removeNode(l2, 0);
    }
}
```

Also when one of your lists runs out, you bail out and ignore the remaining items in the other list.  You could add this code after the above loop:

```
while (l1->size > 0) {
    insertNode(result, index++, l1->head->item);
    removeNode(l1, 0);
}
while (l2->size > 0) {
    insertNode(result, index++, l2->head->item);
    removeNode(l2, 0);
}
```

Not the most efficient, but it should work.

Comment: It stopped working after a while. Any ideas? There's no error message thou. When I ran in debug mode, it told me access violation

Comment: yeah your problem is probably:

`removeNode(l1, 0);`
`insertNode(result, index++, l1->head);`

You are removing l1->head, freeing the memory and then you're trying to add it with insertNode()

Comment: @kcraigie agreed. If you are freeing a node which contains the value and then trying to use the value, that would be most likely what causing your problems.

Comment: But my logic was it will first remove the first item from l1 or l2 then add it into result. Repeat until the size for l1 and l2 < 0. Is that correct?

Comment: But when you call removeNode() it no longer exists, so you can't add it to result.  I'll edit my answer with some more code.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. I modified the sequence by add then remove. But the result that I am getting was 1,2,2,3 only. 4 and 6 were missing. Also, the part that I can only change was the sortedMerge(). The insertNode and removeNode should'nt be modified

Comment: @kcraigie you beat me to it twice, once with the initial comment, then when I was editing my comment ha

Comment: in sorted merge, is index supposed to be i?

Comment: @Plopperzz Sorry, I gave your comment an upvote as a consolation prize ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry it supposed to be i. I changed the naming convention and forget to update the question. The problem now was let's say I entered 1,2,3 for l1 and 2,4,6 for l2. But it only came out as 1,2,2,3 and the 4,6 went missing

Comment: @kcraigie much obliged! As for not being able to change insert and remove, were they already implementations that were provided to you? It now seems like some counting error that might account for the missing elements.

Comment: Yeah they came as part of the question. We only needed to implement the sortedMerge() and the part to populate l1 and l2.

Comment: Yeah like the other answer said, you're not fully handling every element in both lists.  When you get to the end of one of your lists, you bail out, ignoring the last element in the other list.  I'll edit the answer further.

Answer (score 0):

Example merge sorted lists function, and a sort list function that uses an array of pointers to nodes of lists along with the merge lists function to implement a fast sort for linked list.

```
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    if(pSrc1 == NULL)
        return pSrc2;
    if(pSrc2 == NULL)
        return pSrc1;
    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            if(pSrc2 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}

#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* size of aList[] */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];                 /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)       /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                      /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                       /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}
```